# Альтернатива hide() и show()

Tags: jquery, javascript, функции

Как лучше на javascript написать функцию, которая будет выполнять те же действия что и методы jquery `hide()` и `show()`?

Comment: Все просто: на javascript.ru есть кратенькая [инструкция](http://javascript.ru/ui/show-hide-toggle).

Answer (score 6):

```
var obj = document.getElementById('ELEMENT');   
obj.style.display = 'none' =====> $.hide();   
obj.style.display = 'block' =====> $.show();
```

Comment: @ROOT а как-же анимашка? :)

Comment: @ROOT ну это понятно, а анимация?

Comment: Анимация .slideUp(), .slideDown(), .slideLeft(), .slideToggle()